# Excel VBA: Loop and finding multiple values in a range then copying the offset cells in the same range in a categorized list in another worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, loops, range, offset

I am in need of help with looping through a range (In this case Column "C") and finding 5 specific words (Sort, Set, Shine, Standardize, and Sustain) and then offsetting one row below the found value and copying that value to a categorized list on another sheet. To add complexity eliminating duplicate comments and blanks if possible would be great!

This is an imported form to my workbook and i am trying to create a quickly generated list of each comment under each specific word so that i can then copy into a report.

This code is borrowed and i am in need to adding multiple strings to find and be listed under each category.

Code:`Sub Find_Range()
'

```
Dim strFind     As String
Dim oRng        As Range
Dim fRng        As Range
Dim i           As Long


strFind = "SET IN ORDER" ' string to find
Set oRng = Worksheets("IMPORTED DATA").Columns(3) ' column to search

Set fRng = oRng.Cells(oRng.Cells.Count)
For i = 1 To Application.CountIf(oRng, strFind & "*")
    Set fRng = oRng.Cells.Find(What:=strFind, _
                               LookIn:=xlValues, _
                               LookAt:=xlPart, _
                               After:=fRng, _
                               MatchCase:=False)
    If Not fRng Is Nothing Then
        With Worksheets("5S COMMENTS")
            .Cells(i, "A") = fRng.Offset(1, 0).Value2
            '.Cells(i, "B") = fRng.Offset(2, 1).Value2
        End With
    End If
Next i
```

'
End Sub`

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

[Picture of excel list](https://drive.google.com/file/d/15LLYeEH1gkO95818nE6sCK-cec7m0-yH/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Have you tried something like `for each word in Array(...): do whle ...: Find word: ...` or `for each cell in columns("C").cells: select case cell.value ...`?

Comment: I have, I have used multiple examples i have found from forums on pages but for what i'm looking for is not successful and that has led me to creating an account and asking for the assistance lol. I am continuing to try at it but i am hoping for someone to spell it out so i can see what i am missing. Thanks for the reply!!!!

Comment: @Boogs it would be great if you had added a picture of the output format with your post. Remember the clear you can make your demand the faster you will get a response.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of VBA I suggest to use a formula:

```
=LET(
  Source; 'Imported data'!C1:C999;
  Step; 3;
  FirstRow; INDEX(ROW(Source);1;0);
  Criteria; FILTER(Source; MOD(ROW(Source)-FirstRow; Step) = 0);
  Data; FILTER(Source; MOD(ROW(Source)-FirstRow; Step) = 1);
  FILTER(Data; Criteria = INDIRECT("R[-1]C";FALSE)))
```

Here:

- `Source` is a range with data to filter, where the first cell should be the one to check for the specific words
- `Step` is a data chunk size, which is 3 in your case I guess
- `Criteria` is cells to check for specific words
- `Data` is the `Criteria` shifted one row down
- `INDIRECT("R[-1]C", False)` addresses a cell right above the formula
- Put the formula under the word to search for

Comment: @Boogs Let me know if it works for you. If you need a VBA code, then it would be nice to show what you have at the moment.

Comment: Ahhh ok I apologize! I will test this once I’m back at my station - I do appreciate the time and help!

Comment: Unfortunately the formula that you helped me with is only in 365 or Online i believe, I am working off of Excel 2013 (Company software)  i've done a bit more research and found something on the path of what i'm looking for. I have an output of what it is but it definitely needs tweaking.